# How can I speed up MSDeploy?

Tags: msdeploy

MSDeploy is excruciatingly slow.

As in, it has taken our build /deployment process from 3.8 minutes to 15.

Is there anyway to speed this up?  The publish method we are using is WMSVC.

Comment: How large is the deployment package? What providers are you including?

Comment: @RichardSzalay: About 10MB.  Not sure what you mean by what providers I'm including.

Comment: In the output log, does it look like it's deploying the entire site even though not much has changed? If so, see if the `useCheckSum` option mentioned in my answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your configuration (which MSDeploy providers/settings your using), I can only provide vague advice.

If your deployment time has increased, it's possible that the files are having their *last modified* timestamps updated everytime. Since this is the default mechanism MSDeploy uses to determine whether the file should be uploaded, it would cause your entire application to be deployed everytime.

If that sounds right, you can switch to checksum-based syncing by specifying the [`-useCheckSum`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29) command line argument.

Comment: It's worth noting that i've seen a lot of deployment pipelines slow down by *using* *-usechecksum* so it might not always be the ultimate speed saver :-)